# Opacity gradient background colour

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an effect which increases the width of a border up to a certain point, using the thickness of the border to represent a progress bar, and am wondering if there's a nice way to accomplish this while reusing the colours defined in my stylesheets.

Right now I have the element with the border contained within a div, which creates the wider part of the border by using its background color. Then, the outer container's background is styled with a linear gradient, to switch from the color of the inner element's border to the color of the background, like

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red 10%, blue 10%)
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to avoid hard-coding the colors in the background. What I want is to dynamically vary the percentage for where the colors change as a style attribute, but would prefer the colors to be defined as part as a class. So ideally something like:

```
opacity: linear-gradient(to right, 0 10%, opacity 1 10%)
```

That way the code which alters the length of the progress bar doesn't need to be aware of the colors, making it easier for the progress bar colors to be kept consistent with the rest of the website. Any other way to accomplish the same thing would work; changing the width could work, if it didn't impact the width of the child element.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the mask property. Below is a basic example that you can adjust

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right,#000 var(--o), #0000 calc(var(--o) + 10%));
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--o: 20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--o: 50%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--o: 80%"></div>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it seemed to apply the mask to the children elements too. After some googling I found I could avoid that by styling a `:before` element. I was still having some difficulty with the mask, but ended up realizing I could just do `background: linear-gradient(to right, $border-color var(--o), $background-color var(--o));` I hadn't seen the variable injection thing in styles before, so that was helpful, thanks.